# CellMeasurer support of registerChild in react-virtualized

Tags: react-virtualized

Using the render prop registerChild as ref in CellMeasurer seems to be ignored by react-virtualized: warning findDOMNode is deprecated still received.

That comment:

https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/issues/1353#issuecomment-569814307
makes me think that the fix is 4 month old, and latest version of react-virtualized is published 6 month ago

It is already mentioned in the doc though
https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/CellMeasurer.md#using-registerchild, but erroneously:

```
      {({registerChild}) => (
        <div
          style={{
            ...style,
            height: 35,
            whiteSpace: 'nowrap'
          }}
        >
          {content}
        </div>
      )}
```

the div seems to be missing the ref={registerChild} !
Anyway, with or without ref={registerChild} on the div, 
warning findDOMNode is deprecated still received

Answer (score 0):

The point of registerChild is to give the cellMeasurer a ref to the child component removing the need to call findDomNode. Currently the registerChild variable isn't being used, you need to add set the ref of the child component to registerChild.

```
  {({registerChild}) => (
    <div
      ref={registerChild}
      style={{
        ...style,
        height: 35,
        whiteSpace: 'nowrap'
      }}
    >
      {content}
    </div>
  )}
```